# The Color-mix property involving currentColor causes Safari to crash

Tags: css, safari

I tried to use Color-mix together with the currentColor value, but each time it was used, the page in Safari stopped working. Why this happens may not support currentColor. But it shouldn't break the page.

I use Safari 16.5 (18615.2.9.11.4)

```
.block {
background-color: inherit;
color: color-mix(in srgb, currentColor, white 50%)
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? currentColor is the value you define inside color so you have cycle here

Comment: The browser shouldn't crash indeed. Send a report https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: For what it's worth, the latest Technology Preview Release 171 (Safari 16.4, WebKit 18616.1.15) does handle it correctly. So they probably already fixed it. Weird they didn't send a fast-forward patch on stable.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has already been fixed in the latest TP: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256171 I assume this will be shipped in the next stable release.

They wrote a [WPT test](https://wpt.fyi/results/css/css-color/color-mix-currentcolor-003.html?label=experimental&label=master&aligned) that seems to assume `currentColor` is resolved only from inheritance and avoids the recursion, however this test doesn't pass in Chromium. What I believe is the relevant [specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-5/#color-mix) currently state:

> If all [`<color>`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-5/#typedef-color) parameters resolve to the corresponding colors in their respective color spaces, the computed value is the absolute <color> value, in the specified RCS color space, resolved according to [*CSS Color 4* §  14. Resolving <color> Values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#resolving-color-values). Otherwise (if ['currentColor'](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#valdef-color-currentcolor) was used in the function), the computed value is the Relative Color Syntax function with each <color> parameter resolved according to [*CSS Color 4* §  14. Resolving <color> Values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/#resolving-color-values), thus preserving inheritance into child elements.

I must admit I'm not 100% sure of this should read regarding this exact case, but this is anyway the behavior exposed by Firefox, and now Safari, so there is a good chance Chrome will follow soon or ask for the specs to clarify what should happen.

But anyway, you're right, a browser should not crash like that, and if you do spot another such case, you should report it to their vendors.

Comment: Thank you for your instant problem research and alerts on the likely elimination of it in the upcoming release